# Multiple server update architecture

Tags: php, svn, architecture, yii, amazon-web-services

i'm using AWS for my application. current configuration is:
Load balancer --> Multiple EC2 instances (auto scaled) --> all mount a NFS drive with SVN sync

Every time we want to update the application we login to the NFS server (another EC2 instance), and execute svn update to the application folder.

I wanted to know if there is a better way (architecture) to work since i sometime get permission changes after SVN update and server take a while to update. (thought about mounting S3 as a drive).

My app is a PHP + Yii framwork + and mysql DB.

Thanks for the help,
Danny

Comment: Why not just write a script to "svn up" from each EC2 instance?

Comment: it's not clear what's not wrong with your current solution. what does "permission changes" mean, like errors? why does it take a while to update, and what does a while mean? Are you looking for a solution to your current problem or just alternative solutions?

Comment: You can create an autostart script which updates the repository and set the permissions right on each start and then watches the repository for changes.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternate solution since  i believe relying on 1 NFS drive is a bit risky. plus once i update the svn the user updating it is nobody for security reasons...without going in too much not everyone in my team are familiar with Linux system and i wanted to give them an easier interface. last - i'm not sure this is good architecture practice...i just used it as a temp workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a slightly more sophisticated solution:

1. Move all your dynamic directories (`protected/runtime/`, `assets/`, etc.) outside the SVN-Directory (use `svn:ignore`) and symlink them into your app directory. This may require some configuration change in your webserver to follow symlinks, though.

   ```
   /var/www/myapp/config
   /var/www/myapp/runtime
   /var/www/myapp/assets
   /var/www/myapp/htdocs/protected/config-> ../../config
   /var/www/myapp/htdocs/protected/runtime -> ../../runtime
   /var/www/myapp/htdocs/assets -> ../assets
   ```
2. On deployment start with a fresh SVN copy in `htdocs.new` where you create the same symlinks and can fix permissions

   ```
   /var/www/myapp/htdocs.new/protected/config-> ../../config
   /var/www/myapp/htdocs.new/protected/runtime -> ../../runtime
   /var/www/myapp/htdocs.new/assets -> ../assets
   ```
3. Move the `htdocs` to `htdocs.old` and `htdocs.new` to `htdocs`. You may also have to `HUP` the webserver.

This way you can completely avoid the NFS mount as you have time to prepare step 1 and 2. The only challange is to synchronize step 3 on all machines. You could for example use `at` to schedule the update on all machines at the same time.

As a bonus you can always undo a deployment if something goes wrong.

Situation might be more complex if you have to run migrations, though. If the migrations are not backwards compatible with your app, you probably can't avoid some downtime.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer...actually this is exactly how i'm working today (symlinks) what i'm looking for is creating a shared resource (drive) between all servers (which are autoscaled from an AMI image) other then an NFS which is risky (Single point of failure). even with the option to back it up in AWS i think there is a better architecture.